# com.nt.service.JwtUserDetailsService required a bean of type 'com.nt.dao.SpringSecurityDao' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.nt.controller","com.nt.config","com.nt.service","com.nt.dao"})
```

1. List item

   ```
   public class SpringSecurityApplication {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityApplication.class, args);
       }
   //service class
   @Service
   public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

       @Autowired(required=true)
       private SpringSecurityDao dao;

       @Autowired
       private PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;


       public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       /*  UserDao user = dao.findByUsername(username);
           if (user == null) {
       //dao class
   @Repository
   public interface SpringSecurityDao extends CrudRepository<UserDao, Integer> {
       UserDao findByUsername(String username);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It because you put @Autowired(required=true) , you remove it (required=true)

Comment: after remove that attribute required=true. im getteing same error

Comment: is SpringSecurityDao and JwtUserDetailsService are same package , it seems in different packages check whether it imported properly in your service class

Comment: no no both are in different package, its imported properly also.